# scalars() returning first column and leaves out all other columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following code that should get the last known action of users and insert it's timestamp in the user object:

```
async def get_last_activity(users, db):
    user_ids = [user.id for user in users]

    event_query = select(func.max(EventModel.datetime), EventModel.user_id).\
        where(EventModel.user_id.in_(user_ids)).\
        group_by(EventModel.user_id)
    events = (await db.execute(event_query)).scalars()

    for event in events:
        print(event)
        for user in users:
            if event.user_id == user.id:
                user.last_activity = event.datetime
    return users


@router.get(
    '/manageable',
    response_model=Users,
)
async def get_manageable_users(
        db: Session = Depends(get_db)
):
    """ Returns a list of users that the current user can manage """

    # @TODO: get users based on authorization helper.
    users = (await db.execute(select(UserModel))).scalars().all()
    users = await get_last_activity(users, db)

    return [{
        'id': user.id,
        'name': user.name,
        'email': user.email,
        'last_activity': user.last_activity
    } for user in users]
```

This results in the following error:

```
File "./app/api/v1/users/read.py", line 26, in get_last_activity
if event.user_id == user.id:
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'user_id
```

Even though the column is being selected in the generated query:

```
api001_1  | 2021-08-11 09:19:16,514 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT max(events.datetime) AS max_1, events.user_id
api001_1  | FROM events
api001_1  | WHERE events.user_id IN (%s, %s) GROUP BY events.user_id
api001_1  | 2021-08-11 09:19:16,515 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00323s] (1, 2)
api001_1  | 2016-10-07 22:00:29   <---------- print(event)
```

Does anyone know why the user_id column is not showing up in the Event objects?

Update:
It's `scalars()` that is causing the issue. Without it this is the output of `print(event)`:
`(datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 7, 22, 0, 29), 1)`
After running scalars only the datetime is picked up
So scalars seems to completely disregard the last number which is the user_id. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was under the impression that `scalars()` was supposed to map the result to an object. Upon reading the docs more closely, it can only do this with one column. This (optional) parameter defaults to 0 (index of column) and hence only the datetime is picked up.
I'm not using .scalars() anymore and instead have to do row[0], row[1]